# My LSTM network doesn't work while doing inference?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to built a Conv-LSTM network using PyTorch, model is pretty much like an image caption generator, the model learns to predict words pretty good while training but doesn't predict anything while during inference( while calling def sample), can you tell me what is it that I'm not doing right.

Here is the code for the LSTM network

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_size, hidden_size):
    super(LSTM, self).__init__()
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.embed_size = embed_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size , embed_size)
    self.model = nn.LSTM(self.embed_size, self.hidden_size, batch_first=True)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
    self.ln = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.vocab_size)
    self.conv = Conv()
  def forward(self , features, sentence):
    features = self.conv(features)
    embedding = self.embeddings(sentence)
    embedding = torch.cat((features.unsqueeze(1), embedding) , dim = 1 )
    embedding = self.dropout(embedding)
    embedding = embedding.cuda()
#   print(embedding.shape)
    out , _ = self.model(embedding)
#   print("..." , out.shape)
    lipRead = self.ln(out)
    return lipRead
   
   def sample(self , x , max_length):
         words = []
         with torch.no_grad():
           features = self.conv(x)
           print("df" , features.shape)                       # batch , 10
           state = None
           for n in range(36):
              out , state = self.model(features.unsqueeze(1) , state)
#                print(out.shape)                             # batch_size , 1 , 10
              out = self.ln(out)
#               print(out)
#               print(out.shape)                              # batch , 1 , 40
              pred = out.squeeze(1).argmax(1)
#               print("predicted" , pred)
#               print("pred shape:" , pred.shape)             # batch
              words.append(pred[2])
              features = self.embeddings(pred).to(device)
#              print(features.shape)                          #batch , 10
            
         return words
```

I think self.ln or self.model are not able to predict the correct output, but if that's so then why does the model learns to predict the correct words while training.

here is how I did the inference, as you can see the predicted value is not meaningful.

```
for j , (x , y) in enumerate(val_data):
    x = x.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
    x = x.to(device)
    y = torch.from_numpy(y)
    y = y.to(device)
    print("real value: " , y[2])
    words = model.sample(x , 36)
    print("predicted: " , words)
```

output

```
real value:  tensor([ 1,  8, 13, 39, 22,  7,  8, 19,  4, 39,  1, 24, 39,  6, 39, 13,  8, 13,
         4, 39, 18, 14, 14, 13, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38],
       device='cuda:0')
df torch.Size([16, 10])
predicted:  [tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0'), tensor(39, device='cuda:0')]
```

You can check this [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/technoboard/notebook112a4a579c?scriptVersionId=142025649) for reproducing the issue.

Comment: The code is not reproducible, please provide a clean and executable code.
In the sample function, where are you taking the variable features from?
In the forward part you're correctly extracting the features with the conv layer (which you didn't specify exactly what it is).

Comment: hey @Deusy94 thanks for taking a look at my code, I've edited the question so you can check it again. I've also uploaded a notebook on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/technoboard/notebook112a4a579c?scriptVersionId=142025649) for the sake of reproducibility. Also the conv net is a 3d CNN which take the input video of shape (batch , 1 , 75 , height , width) and outputs a tensor.

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different inputs to the model forward during the train and test.
During the training procedure, the input is the cat embeddings of features and sentences.
The model is trained with this information, it expects the same input in the test.